# How do nuclear physicists know if a particularly long-lived nuclear isomer actually exists? If it never seems to emit a gamma ray?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-isomers

Some nuclear isomers (like tantalum-180m) have never even been observed to decay....

How do we know it is in an excited state then?  That it actually absorbed some form of energy?

Can these includes be induced to decay and emit a gamma ray, even if they never spontaneously do so?

Comment: ENSDF has pointers to many references.

Comment: For one thing the isomers should differ in their mass, which means that precision mass spectrometry should show multiple states, rather than a singlet. You are correct, stimulated emission would also allow us to de-excite such states, but I don't know if such experiments can be carried out with the current x-ray and gamma sources.

Comment: @FlatterMann does this mean we can almost create gamma ray lasers? Terrifying.

Comment: @user253751 Have you seen a modern free electron laser beamline? You definitely don't want to stand anywhere close when the beam is on. Having said that, gammas don't deposit much of their energy in solids, so they are somewhat pointless as weapons.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the heavy elements currently present in the Universe were created in Supernova events.

After the big bang, when the Universe had expanded enough for the temperature to have decreased enough to allow elements to form, the elements present were mostly Hydrogen and Helium, with very little heavy elements. It is in stars that fusion creates elements heavier than Hydrogen and Helium, and it is in supernova events that elements heavier than Iron are created.

In supernova events (isotopes of) elements are created in proportion to the probability of each of those creation events.

After a supernova event the remnents of the supernova can join a new coalescence process, with formation of a star out of interstellar gas that is enriched with heavy elements. Some of the proto-stellar material may form planets that orbit that star.

Formation of Tantalum-180m is of low probability, but not zero probability. Given the sheer amount of matter involved in a star: if Tantalum-180m *can* form, it *will* form.

Answer (score 0):

For any given nucleus, it is possible to calculate its net binding energy for various configurations (positions) of the protons and neutrons in it, including which way all their spins are organized. The most likely packing of the nucleons is the one which maximizes the binding energy, resulting in the most stable nucleus.

You can then perturb the nucleus in your binding energy model by pulling it out of round  or re-arranging the spins and recalculating the binding energy for any weird configuration you want. the difference in energy between the most stable or "ground" state of the nucleus and what it has in the deformed state is the energy which must be put into the nucleus to get it deformed, and will be the amount released when this excited state decays back into the ground state.

Now, the most likely lifetime of the excited state can itself be calculated knowing the size of that energy difference and a bunch of other quantum considerations (including, for example, the tunneling probability for nucleons to leak through a potential barrier that traps them in a metastable state) and from that you get a half-life for the *nuclear isomer*.

Then you discover that the theoretically-calculated half-life for certain isomers is really, really long while for others it is extremely short.

Since the energy release in a nuclear isomer decay process is of the order ~gamma rays, the expected decay product will be a gamma-ray photon- which led some physicists to conclude that if you had a large number of metastable isomers and beamed them with gamma rays, you could trigger their simultaneous decay and thereby make a bomb far more powerful than any chemical bomb yet less powerful than a fission bomb- and that bomb would be extremely compact and easy to carry around.

But no conclusive evidence exists that you can in fact trigger that all-at-once decay with a gamma ray beam- so the *isomer bomb* remains a science-fiction weapon only.